# css manipulation using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom-manipulation

i am running into a problem with animation using javascript bookmarklet. it is not working properly on some website which have header and footer. my animation div should display over all other content. but it is working like this. here is my code please give solution. also it should display in center on mobile device.

```
meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name="viewport";
meta.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.8";
document.head.appendChild(meta);
cont= document.createElement('div');
cont.setAttribute("class","container");
cont.style.width= "100%";
cont.style.height= "100vh"; 
cont.style.background= "black";
cont.style.display= "flex";
cont.style.alignitems= "center";
cont.style.justifycontent= "center";
cont.style.position= "absolute";
cont.style.top= "50%";
cont.style.left= "50%";
cont.style.transform= "translate(-50%, -50%)";
document.body.appendChild(cont);

dd = document.createElement("div");
dd.setAttribute("id","np");          
dd.style.border= "16px solid #f3f3f3";
dd.style.borderRadius= "50%";
dd.style.borderTop= "16px solid blue";
dd.style.borderRight= "16px solid green";
dd.style.borderBottom= "16px solid red";
dd.style.borderLeft = "16px solid pink";
dd.style.width= "150px";
dd.style.height= "150px";
dd.style.position= "fixed";

dd.style.bottom= "50%";        
dd.style.right= "40%";        
dd.style.left= "40%";        
dd.style.top= "40%";

document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(dd);
const divElem = document.getElementById('np');
let rotate360 = [
      { transform: 'rotate(360deg)' }
    ];

    let slowInfinite = {
      duration: 1000,
      iterations: Infinity
    };

divElem.animate( rotate360, slowInfinite );
```

[should work like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jccys.png)
[but working like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Tqc.png)

Comment: You probably need also to set a Zindex value to bring it on top of all

Comment: You are looking to write a modal, easy stuff insert the element at the lowest part of the HTML>body. Then you may call z-index to plate and float the element above everything else.

Comment: what should z index value .

Comment: Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements).

Note: If two positioned elements overlap without a z-index specified, the element positioned last in the HTML code will be shown on top.

Comment: An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: So with all that if you follow the order -> Place lowest HTML -> Position -> z-index it should float above everything!

Comment: @BGPHiJACK elements here receive transform and/or position, zindex can be indeed reset if not high enough. We have no idea of the zindex set on what ever else stands in that page/document.

Comment: This is why we place the element at the lowest point in the body this will bypass many elements with Z-Index and so we're only left to worry about few elements potentially colliding. In those cases I'd leave that to the developer adding this to their domain or offer an API to control it better.